# Print CoreData on tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, tableview

I have 2 different test cases here. In case 1 this is what I used to print the entire amount of entries from CoreData and it works. I have tried to do the exact same thing in app2 but it does not work. All I want to do is in each individual cell with all of the core data entries.

APP1

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    user = coreDataHandler.getSortedData()

    for i in user! {
        displayL.text = String(i.username)
    }
}
```

APP2

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    user = coreDataHandler.getSortedData()

    return user!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = cctv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    for i in user! {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = String(describing: i.username)
        return cell!
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: What type is `username` that you need to create a `String` from? And never *get data* in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to print all the user entry in each cell then you can try below solution,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    user = coreDataHandler.getSortedData()

    return user!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    for i in user! {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = String(describing: i.username)
    }

    return cell!
}
```

and if you want to print each entry in each cell the try below solution,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    user = coreDataHandler.getSortedData()

    return user!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    let currentUser  = user[indexPath.row]

    cell?.textLabel?.text = String(describing: currentUser.username)

    return cell!
}
```

Note: This is just a pseudo might contain error

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong

Do like this

```
let user: [UserType] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    user = coreDataHandler.getSortedData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return user.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    let currentUser = user[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(currentUser.username)"
    return cell!
}
```

You don't need iterate again in `cellForRowAt` delegate as it is self iterated delgate.

For safe coding use `guard let` or `if let` for unwrapping values.
Force unwrap leads to app crash in any instance of time.